# TimeOut doesn't work, even with sinon.useFakeTimer()

Tags: javascript, timer, timeout, mocha.js, sinon

Env: Mocha, Sinon, node.js. Why this test is executed in 8ms when there's a timeOut of 5500ms in it? Maybe i don't understand what timers are? i mean, it should iddle the execution right? not finish the test till timer is out.

```
var   sinon     = require('sinon');
var   chai      = require('chai');

 expect = chai.expect;
 should = chai.should();
 assert = chai.assert;

var clock;
beforeEach(function () {
    clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
});

afterEach(function () {
    clock.restore();
});

it("should time out after 5000 ms", function() {
    var timedOut = false;
    setTimeout(function () {
        timedOut = true;
    }, 5000);

    timedOut.should.be.false;
    clock.tick(5500);
    timedOut.should.be.true;
});
```

Comment: `sinon.useFakeTimers()` replaces the global `setTimeout` function with a version that runs its callback synchronously (immediately) upon the fake clock being ticked beyond the timer's timeout value. That's why the test runs quickly. And that's a good thing, you don't want your unit tests to take 5 seconds per test.

Answer (score -1):

I found the way to make a setTimeOut works in Mocha for node.js.

```
// We need to pass the mocha's function 'done' that tells mocha to wait till this function is called
it('It should wait around 5 seconds', function(done){

    // We augment mocha's timeout to more than default 2000ms
    // we put more than the 5 seconds of setTimeout to asure us
    this.timeout(6 * 1000);

    setTimeout(function(){

        // tells mocha we are finished
        done();

    }, 5*1000);
});
```

This is a substitute for 'wait' function in jasmine.